# clear and add widget loop crash

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I have a problem, I have a for loop that for every string clears all widgets and adds a label with the string on the press of a button.
Everytime I press the button it crashes , but when I take the for loop out it does what it's told
(only once) without crashing.
Should i leave it some time between each operation or what.
Help please

Comment: Could you post your traceback?

Comment: @SmeltQuake There is nothing , that's the problem , no errors no nothing , it just acts like i closed the app (its running on android)

Comment: There is still a python traceback, retrieve it following [these instructions](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform). If it doesn't help you to solve the problem, post it here.